# Browse a folder tree using powershell

Tags: powershell, ssl

I have the following code that browses the path `Cert:\LocalMachine\My` to have information about SSL certificates. I want to know how to do to browse all folders in `Cert:\LocalMachine` and to get their information. I know that I need to add another loop but i did not know how to do it.

This is the script I wrote:

```
$route = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"

$count = (Dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My\*).Count
$count=$count-1

For ($i=0; $i -le $count; $i++)
{ 
$subject = (Get-ChildItem $route)[$i].Subject
$thumb = (Get-ChildItem $route)[$i].Thumbprint


$expiredate = (Get-ChildItem $route)[$i].NotAfter
$startDate = Get-Date
$diff = (New-TimeSpan -Start $startDate -End $expiredate)
$days = $diff.Days
if ($diff.Days -ge 0)
{ 
 if ($diff.Days -gt 30)
 {

 }
 if($diff.Days -lt 30)
 {

  $mailtext3 = "are about to expire in less then"
  $mailtext4 = "days" 
  $content= "$mailtext1,$subject,$mailtext3 $days $mailtext4"
  Add-Content -Path C:\Users\hmk\Desktop\file.txt -Value "$content" 

$expiredate
}

}
elseif($diff.Days -lt 0)
{

$mailtext3 = "already expired since"
$mailtext4 = "days"
$content= "$subject, $mailtext3,$days,$mailtext4" 
Add-Content -Path C:\Users\hmk\Desktop\file.txt -Value "$content" 
}
}
```

I hope I can get an answer as soon as possible

Comment: Start off by just getting all the certificate detail: $Certs = Get-ChildItem -Path "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -Recurse then do a ForEach loop over this object

Comment: I want to have access to "Cert:\LocalMachine\" subfolders. I tried ForEach but did not work out

Comment: then just use `$Certs = Get-ChildItem -Path "Cert:\LocalMachine" -Recurse`

Comment: I tried it and it gives me all files , which is okay , until I execute New-TimeSpan and , that cannot work because there are some files that are not certificates

Comment: The objects have the PsIsContainer note property so you can fitler out the non-certificates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
$StartDate = Get-Date
$CertPath = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My\'
$CertsDetail =  Get-ChildItem -Path $CertPath -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer -ne $true } | ForEach-Object {
    $DaysLeft = (New-TimeSpan -Start $StartDate -End $_.NotAfter).Days
    If ($DaysLeft -lt 30) {
        $Under30 = $true
    }
    Else {
        $Under30 = $false
    }
    If ($DaysLeft -lt 1) {
        $Expired = $true
    }
    Else {
        $Expired = $false
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{Subject = $_.Subject;`
                    Thumbprint = $_.Thumbprint;`
                    ExpireDate = $_.NotAfter;`
                    ExpiryDaysRemaining = $DaysLeft;`
                    Under30Days = $Under30;`
                    Expired = $Expired
                    }

}

Write-Host "Expiring in under 30 days:"
$CertsDetail | Where-Object { ($_.Under30Days) -and !($_.Expired)}

Write-Host "Expired:"
$CertsDetail | Where-Object { $_.Expired}
```

Comment: It worked so well, thank you, but I want to know how to write the output in a file instead of the command line

Comment: Just pipe it to a file instead then. CSV is usually the most useful: $CertsDetail | Where-Object { $_.Expired} | Export-Csv -Path 'c:temp\filename.csv'

Comment: I tried it and it worked well.There still one last thing to ask ,In the CSV file i get @{ at each line and } at the end. Is there a possibility write the content without them??